# How do I add associations between tables using rails generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The title says it all really. It seems to me that rails generate model mystuff
will generate a model which is empty apart from

```
class mystuff < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

It also generates a migration file which I can send to the database with

```
rake db:migrate
```

which is great until I want to throw in a has_many relationship. In this case I go back to the model so that it looks like for example:

```
 class mystuff < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    end
```

Then I run `rake db:migrate` again but because the migration file hasn't been updated nothing interesting happens.

So then I run

```
rails generate migration mystuff and the migration file appears.
```

Great. Now I want to update the database itself so I run `rake db:migrate` again and the schema updates. All of this is a bit wordy so is there a way I can just generate all the associations when I'm generating the model. That would be easier

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` will not create a database migration for you.  It lets you set an association between the classes.  You would have to create a new migration on your own to add a column.  If you are familiar with foreign keys, the `belongs_to` will typically go on the class (model) where the FK is contained.

For example, if a Status is associated with a Task (i.e. you want a status_id for a "Task", you would add a `belongs_to` on the Task and a `has_one` or `has_many` to the Status.  You then generate a migration to add a status_id to the tasks table i.e. something like:  `rails g migration AddStatusToTasks status:references`.